# Posting array of objects in React is giving me an extra object

Tags: reactjs, arrays, object, post, state

I am trying to post an array of objects. They show up in my HTML but when I console.log it always gives me an extra empty object. Which my backend doesn't love.

Here's the code on codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-herschel-u8byqj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

And here is the code:

```
const [animal, setAnimal] = useState('');

const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState<any>([])

const handleAdd = (text: any) => {

const newAnimal = {
  id: uuidv4(),
  animal: text
}
setInitialState([newAnimal, ...initialState]);

console.log(initialState)
}

return (
<div>
  
       <FormControl fullWidth>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Animal</InputLabel>
    <Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
      id="demo-simple-select"
      value={animal}
      label="Animal"
      onChange={(e: any) => setAnimal(e.target.value)}
      name='worksFrom'
    >
      <MenuItem value='cow'>Cow</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value='pig'>Pig</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value='horse'>Horse</MenuItem>
    </Select>
    <Button disabled={!animal} onClick={() => handleAdd(animal)}>Add</Button>
  </FormControl>
  {
    initialState.map((x: any) => {
      return (
        <div key={x.id}>{x.animal}</div>
      )
    })
  }
</div>
 )
 }
```

I have tried a lot of different things but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please read [ask] (again if necessary), especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem" where it notes "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so— **but also copy the code into the question itself**."

Comment: Although it’s handy to have a fiddle please include the relevant code.

Comment: Cheers! Fixed it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, you should remove the object you are adding initially at:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);
```

and then, perhapes you don't want to send empty animals, so you should add a if clause at your handleAdd to handle this situation:

```
const handleAdd = (text) => {
    if (text.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const newAnimal = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      animal: text
    };
    setInitialState([newAnimal, ...initialState]);
  };
```

this should help you. good luck with your studies;

Answer (score 0):

You're always initializing the array with an empty animal, because the animal state is always initialized as an empty text. Initialize the array to be empty and add some logic to enable adding animals only if the option was selected.

```
  const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState([]);
```

And to avoid adding an empty animal you could disable the button if the animal state is falsey.

```
<Button disabled={!animal} onClick={handleSubmit}>Add</Button>
```

That should disable the button unless you pick an animal from the select component.

Comment: My array is still empty on first click with those changes. Even tho it shows up in the html :P So in my database i have "cow", "pig" and "", even tho i chose horse too

Comment: Did you add the disabled condition in the button? If that's the case you should not be able to press it unless a selection has been made in the select.